# jquery If statement based on a previous element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide an element if the previous element has a number less than 0.

https://jsfiddle.net/82bysjag/2/

```js
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $(".hide").each(function() {
    var prevqty = $(".hide").prev().text();

    if (prevqty < 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {}
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  -2
</div>
<div class="hide">
  Hide
</div>

<div>
  1
</div>
<div class="hide">
  Hide
</div>
```

Is there an error with my **var prevqty**?

Comment: try `var prevqty = parseInt($(".hide").prev().text());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $(this) and parseInt to

```js
$(".hide").each(function() {
  var prevqty = parseInt($(this).prev().text(), 10);
  if (prevqty < 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>-2</div>
<div class="hide">Hide</div>
```

Comment: Using parseInt() not important

Comment: @charlietfl but isn't it all in good practice when comparing integers?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from prevqty. JavaScript is seing it as a string. Convert it to number first as follows;

```
 var prevqty = $(".hide").prev().text();
 prevqty =Number(prevqty );
```

Then you can compare

Comment: This is only working for the first element with the class and not any after: https://jsfiddle.net/82bysjag/10/

Comment: $(".hide").prev() in your each() callback will always reselect all matching element while .text() only picks the text of first element (which will always be '-2'). Change var prevqty = $(".hide").prev().text() to var prevqty = $(this).prev().text();